# Legendre's Conjecture

Tags: number-theory

I have read and heard conflicting reports about whether or not Legendre's conjecture has been proven. Refresh: Legendre believed that there will always be at least one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

Most websites have told me that it remains unproven, however a few claim that it has. The main article is: http://vixra.org/pdf/1303.0048v1.pdf

The article was written sometime last year and claims to have a proof but many other sites updated recently say it remains unsolved.

So, is it solved or unsolved?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't trust things posted at vixra.

Comment: That would represent an enormous leap in our knowledge about prime gaps. Skepticism is warranted.

Comment: I'd say *extreme* skepticism is warranted.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but this was also asked here: [A Proof of Legendre's Conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846651/a-proof-of-legendres-conjecture)
where Gina points out there is an error in one of the inequalities, rendering the proof invalid.

In short, yes, Legendre's Conjecture remains unresolved.